# Remove # from path in Angular 2

Tags: angular2-routing

I know this isn't a new question but I didn't find a working solution. I'm working on a project using HashLocationStrategy and I need to remove # sign from url. I'm tryng to change to PathLocationStrategy following various posts but anyone works for me. My app.module is:

```
import { routing } from './app.route';
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    routing
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy },
  ... ]
})
```

app.route is:

```
export const routes: Routes = [

{ path: "myComponent",    component: MyComponent },
  path: "**",  component: HomeComponent }

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

I need to build the project and put it in a specific folder on server, so in index.html I put:

```
<base href="/myapp/">
```

When I run the app and try to reach a page using path like "http://myServer/myApp/myComponent" I get 404 error, but with "http://myServer/myApp/#/myComponent" it works.
Is there any change to do to pass to PathLocationStrategy?

Comment: the base href should point to the full url, not local from the server url, something like `http://localhost:8080/myapp/`

Comment: Sure, I tried with full path but I ometted here for brevity. Thanks